# PUT/POST Double Quotes without escaping to external server

Tags: javascript, double-quotes

**Explanation:**

I am trying to POST/PUT the following text

> {"email":"DD@GMAIL.COM"}

via *xhttp.send* to an external server. I *need* to post the double quotes with it, but how do I do that? I read about htmlentities, specialchars et cetera but I still, after an hour or more, can not find the solution. And of course, this would not work (because of the double quotes clash):

```
xhttp.send("{"email":"DD@GMAIL.COM"}");
```

**This is the script until now:**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h1>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Request data</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("PUT", "http://www.example.com/json", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', "csrf_token");
  xhttp.send("fname=Henry"); //TODO: MAKE SURE THAT EXACTLY     {"email":"DD@GMAIL.COM"}       WILL BE 'POSTED'.
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Please help me, I can not figure this out.

Comment: Escape them or use single quotes as delimiter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the string in single quotes

```
xhttp.send('{"email":"DD@GMAIL.COM"}');
```

However, it's best to serialize it to a string from an object

```
xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({ email :"DD@GMAIL.COM"}));
```

Also you should send the correct content-type header

```
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify` is the way to go. Much better than crafting JSON manually by escaping, or quoting.

Answer (score 0):

It's JavaScript, not HTML (well, it is embedded in HTML, but inside a script element so you only have to worry about the squence `</` as far as the HTML is concerned).

The escape character in JavaScript is `\`.

```
xhttp.send("{\"email\":\"DD@GMAIL.COM\"}");
```

Since you don't use single quotes in the data, you could use them to delimit the string instead of escaping the content:

```
xhttp.send('{"email":"DD@GMAIL.COM"}');
```

Or you could use a JavaScript object and convert it to JSON:

```
var object = {email:"DD@GMAIL.COM"};
var json = JSON.stringify(object);
xhttp.send(json);
```

---

Aside…

> ```
> xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
> ```

The content-type for JSON is `application/json`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use single quote to wrap it:    `'{"email":"DD@GMAIL.COM"}'`